# Get reviews from user

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Any way to get a given amount of Places reviews made by a single Google+ user?
Google+ APIs don't seem to have such feature, did I miss such feature in Places API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Places API does not currently support this feature. If you believe this would be a useful feature you can submit a 'Places API - Feature Request' [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request).